# Key Metrics report with adobe analytics web service

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am using the adobe analytics web service API to get information from the omniture reporting suite.

Anyway, in order to get a report I need the report ID, which I can't get because it doesn't display that information anywhere. In the main page we have a report called 'Key Metrics' that I need the report ID for. Anyone know how to get the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to pull a specific report directly from the interface, instead you have to build it via [Report.Queue](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/r-queue) with a [reportDescription](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/r-reportdescription-1) using the same metrics, time frame, etc. as you use in the interface. This will return a report ID that you can then later use to check the status of & get the results from.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a report in the UI, you can generate the API call to generate that report from the API using the following technique.

https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/blog/quickly-creating-analytics-api-reports-from-a-ui-report
(images seem to be missing, the the text describes it clearly enough)

This will get you most of what you need, it is just not the exact same report instance as in the UI, but that should not be an issue.