# List all dimensions and metrics of Report Suite Adobe Analytics

Tags: metrics, dimensions, adobe-analytics

**My problem is**:  I try to list all the different dimensions and Metrics of one Report in order to check and control what are we doing, but I'm unable to find an easy way to list them without finding a lot of repeated elements in the portal. IS there any way to list them?

**Why is it happening:** I've tried to get in my report suite an get into one workspace just to check if I could get the metrics of it, but I found that there are a lot of metrics repeated (I didn't do the development so I'm not sure what they've did.
So if I get to a report and list the metrics I found that the same metric could be used in another report, so it's impossible to know if I'm counting them correctly.
I also tried to connect to the account via PowerBI but seems that I have the same problem, I see a lot of metrics that are repeated. (exapmle Bellow).

[image]

I consulted the following links but they didn't helped me:
https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/user/analytics_user.pdf

https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2019/04/23/adobe-analytics-report-suite-checklist/

[Key Metrics report with adobe analytics web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550102/key-metrics-report-with-adobe-analytics-web-service?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are an Administrator, you can see all the metrics, including calculated metrics, and dimensions for a report suite in the Analytics Admin Console, and adjust their settings.

If you are not an Administrator, you can only see the metrics for which you've been given permission to.

You can also query the list of metrics and dimensions via API, using the /metrics, /dimensions, and /calculatedmetrics endpoints but these methods will also only give you access to what you have permission to see.

https://www.adobe.io/apis/experiencecloud/analytics/docs.html
https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis

There is also a handy Swagger UI you can use to test API methods. https://adobedocs.github.io/analytics-2.0-apis/

Pro tip:  In Analysis Workspace, you can use the browser's network traffic tool to see the API methods that Workspace is making across the wire to retrieve lists of metrics and dimensions.

In many cases, the duplicate metrics are because people in your organization have made calculated metrics with the same names that are visible to you because you are an admin or because they shared them out to you. If you are an admin you can try to clean these duplicates up in the Calculated Metrics manager but it's hard to tell whether they're currently in use in specific Workspace projects or API methods.

Pro tip:  If an Admin deletes a calculated metric or segment that is currently used in a project, that CM or segment will still function in the project, they just won't show up in the visible CM/segment list for users.